# I like to know where I have to paste css grid html code in wordpress?

Tags: css, grid

I want to use CSS Grid to make 3 columns in the head section:

1-title section
2-logo section
3-telefoon number section

for my WordPress theme.
so I like to know where I have to paste this CSS grid HTML(container) code in WordPress theme. this is  the HTML code of CSS grid as an example:

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="grid-item1">title</div>

  <div class="grid-item2">logo</div>

  <div class="grid-item3">telefoon number</div>
 </div>
```

do I have to paste this HTML code in header.php  or in page section of WordPress theme (with code editor)
or it can both, if yes which method is more professional?

Answer (score 0):

im not familiar with wordpress yet but as for the CSS code you can set alter the position of your content to align them the way you want it to.

you can set the 1-title to float to left 2-logo align center and 3- telefoon float right.

thanks let me know if it worked or not :P